# Horizontal Scrolling dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking to implement a site, with React, that scrolls horizontally.

I'm not sure how to implement i few things so i thought i'd get some help.

I have multiple container Divs inside a wrapper

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="section" id="section1"> <!-- Needs to be 100% of screen -->
    <h2>Section Header</h2>
    <p>
      Some Text
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="section" id="section2"> <!-- Needs to be 100% of screen -->
    <h2>Section Header</h2>
    <p>
      Some Text
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want each .section to take up 100% of the width of the screen (not the parent) and i want them to scroll horizontally.

```
.wrapper{
  background:#000;
  width:12000px; /* Needs to change depending on content */
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  bottom:0px;
}
```

So my problem is, i don't want to have to put a specific width to the wrapper (You can see in my example i am using 12000px) I'd like this to be dynamic.

```
.section{
  width: 4000px; /* Needs to be 100% of the client screen size */
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}
```

So what is the best way for me to make the .wrapper dynamic, so it changes width depending on what is inside of it? and the .sections classes take up 100% of the screen width (Not 100% of it's parent)?

Also, bonus points if anyone can point me in the right direction to find out how to take over the mousewheel behavior...?

Thanks.

Comment: you can achieve horizontal scrolling using jQuery Custom Scrollbar - [link](http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/complete_examples.html). It's has custom options too that are given in its documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

**JS:**

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.scrolls').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
                this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 40);
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
  background: #EFEFEF;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #999;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px !important;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.scrolls {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 80px;
  white-space: nowrap
}

.scrolls img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="scrolls">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/akqp2LoL/1/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, this does sort of work for me but doesn't solve my problem. It allows me to set up everything horizontally but the content withing the .scroll is fixed width, I want each container to take up 100% of the screen width so each .section will be full width no matter what the screen size is.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main{

}
.wrapper{
  height:300px;
width:400px;
overflow-x:auto;
overflow-y:hidden;
}
.section{
  width: 4000px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="section" id="section1">
    <h2>Section Header</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, this solution allows for fixed width but i need to it to be based on the screen size of the client.